# Control the precision displayed for doubles

Tags: c++, string, double, double-precision

Is theres a simple way in c++ to increase the precision of a double that is even:

For instance

```
 double d = 3.6
```

would be

```
d = 3.600 (adding 2 zeros)
```

this d is then sent to a string-class

```
std::to_string(d);
```

You may ask why? I am using a GUI (gtkmm) and in the textview every number produced has to have the same length.

This is the result if the length is not the same:

```
4.396       3.957       11
4.183       3.783       10
3.959       3.6     9
3.723       3.404       8
3.474       3.194       7
3.207       2.967       6
2.919       2.719       5
```

***Is it possible to increase the decimals - that is adding extra zeros when the value is a primitive, or do I have to manipulate the string afterwards instead?***

EDIT: I should have been more clear - I am not interested in std::cout . The output abow represent a GUI

Comment: You could use sprintf for printing more decimal digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you are not changing the precision of the type `double`. To add "extra zeros" if the number is too short, you can use `std::stringstream` as follows:

```
std::stringstream s;
double d = 3.6;
s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << d;
std::string res = s.str();
std::cout << res;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/134fe3b0786dfa52)

The above will set the digit precision to `3` digits and print `3.600`.

Comment: thanks i'll look into this and maybe accept the answer

Comment: @user3155478 You should include `<iomanip>` like in the live demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it compiled but when running it crashed. I did not use the debugger but I tested to change the std::stringstream to std::ostringstream. Now it works :-) :-) .. but I wonder why the app crashes with std::stringstream?